# I want to ask why we use leaving for in this sentence. Do you have a flight leaving for New York

Tags: present-participles

> Do you have a flight leaving for New York?

I would like to ask about this sentence why don't use leave for instead of leaving for.

Comment: What do you know about participles?

Comment: No actually I want to know. Which one is correct.

Comment: I want to know which one is correct. Do you have a flight leaving for New York. Or Do you have a flight to leave for New York.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "leaving for New York" is a participle phrase.  It is headed by a verb's participle form, the "present participle" is used for active senses.  Participles act a bit like adjectives: they modify or describe things.

Here the phase "leaving for New York" modifies the word "flight" and tells you which particular flight the person is talking about. (There is also a past participle, that is used in passive constructions)

This use of participles can often be paraphrased with a relative clause

> a flight *that is* leaving for New York.

Relative clauses also modify or describe.  You can often change a relative cause into a participle phrase.